# Is it safe to have a connection to a central database from a desktop application?

Tags: .net, database-connection, desktop-application

So I do need to develop a C# desktop application which will be installed on several machines (for several clients) and all application data will be stored in one centralized database.

Now I do have some problems in mind. The rough idea is to have each table storing records of all my users, identified by a unique field, say UserID. Now I need each user to be able to access the data associated to his ID only and not the others, which I aim to achieve by using WHERE (UserID = ..) clause in the SQL SELECT query. However, having the database connection open seems to create a confusion in my mind and searching around doesn't help in clearing that doubt concerning security.

How safe it is to have a central DB with a table storing data for more than one users? If not so much, what is the best way of going about it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move from a 2 tier to a 3 tier with a data/business layer in between.  Use WCF from the client to the business/data layer on the server.